# Concurrent List Modification

Tags: java

Below is some code (removed much of it for clarity) which shows my issue of concurrent list modification:

```
for (final Week week : this.demand.getWeeks().getAllWeeks()) {
    final List<Week> weeksExcludingThisWeek = this.demand.getWeeks().getAllWeeks();
    weeksExcludingThisWeek.remove(week);
}
```

As far as I was aware I was removing the reference to the same week object, but in a different list than is used in the for loop.

How do I prevent this from occurring?

Comment: Why you declared weeksExcludingThisWeek  as final?

Comment: I set eclipse to automatically set any non modified variables as final on save. I find it useful to pin point odd errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually copy it into a new list before removing the element:

```
List<Week> weeksExcludingThisWeek = new ArrayList<>(this.demand.getWeeks().getAllWeeks());
```

You are currently removing the week from the same list you are iterating.

Comment: Perfect, that fixed it. Thank you Andy, I'll accept your answer in 8 mins.

Answer (score 2):

Use iterator to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException`s

Have a look at docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

You will find:

> Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics

Comment: Seems new to me, thanks for info!!

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using `this.demand.getWeeks().getAllWeeks()`
For both iteration variable `week`  and inside for loop variable `weeksExcludingThisWeek` .

Same reference in two object that is the issue. You couldn't modify current iterating object inside the loop.

Create new object inside loop, `new ArrayList(this.demand.getWeeks().getAllWeeks())`